# Transaction Stuck - Cannot Cancel or speed up

Tags: metamask

I did this transaction about two years ago trying to buy a Zed-Run horse on OpenSea. I never received the NFT to my Metamask wallet, nor did I ever receive my Eth back. It has been stuck in submitted status since then. I included a screenshot here. When I attempt to cancel or speed up. It has that I have insufficient funds to speed it up even though it says the fee is <0.0001 eth. Has anyone had this issue before ?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrQQ8.png]

Comment: Screenshot is missing